# On level 9, Goromorg Temple I, how do you get through the third central door?

Tags: legend-of-grimrock

The door is just past a trap door that opens and closes every couple seconds, next to a teleportation field also appears and disappears. I can get past this obstacle, but the lever does nothing. How do I proceed past this puzzle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual, the act of typing it all out makes me think of another couple things to try. I had not noticed that there was a pressure plate behind the grate to the left; placing something on that plate quickly before the floor fell out opened the way to a second lever and the solution; both the left and right lever were necessary to open the way.

Comment: On a side note: Once you've opened the grate on the left, got into that hall then press the hidden button on the left wall to stop the trapdoor. Note that you should wait until it shuts though as it can be frozen in the open position.